# How to use Model in EditForm

Tags: blazor

I'm a little confused about how to reference an object in the Model attribute of EditForm.  I've seen @person and simply person used. I'm not sure what's right or if I'm just misunderstanding what I'm seeing it code examples.  Here's a code example of what I'm talking about.  If someone could elaborate a bit I'd appreciate it.

Thank you!

```
<EditForm Model="@person> <= or sometimes shown as just "<EditForm Model="person">"
</EditForm>

@code {
    Person person = new Person();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters) the use of the '@' prefix for nonliterals - even when they are not strictly required.

> Outside of string parameters, we recommend use the use of the @ prefix
> for nonliterals, even when they aren't strictly required.

Here's a quick summary on when to use, and not to use @ when assigning Parameter values, as I understand from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#component-parameters):

- string literals: Don't use @ (mandatory)
- string nonliterals: Use @ (mandatory)
- non-string literals: Don't use @ (recommendation)
- non-string nonliterals: Use @ (recommendation)